# Proving that the 4-potential respects Lorenz gauge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, gauge

We solved the maxwell equations $$ \Box \, A_{ret}^\mu =\frac{4 \pi}{c} J^\mu \tag{1}$$ using the Green function method finding

$$ A^\mu = \frac{4 \pi}{c} \int d^4x' G_{ret} (x-x') J^\mu(x') \tag{2}$$

To see if it respects the Lorenz gauge ($\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$) we explicitly calculate its derivative and obtain

$$ \partial_\mu A^\mu = - \frac{4 \pi}{c} \int d^4x'\bigl(\partial_\mu' \, G_{ret}(x-x')\bigr) J^\mu(x') \tag{3} $$

Now through the Gauss theorem we pass from $4$-dimensional volume integration to a an integral over a $3$D hypersurface imbedded in the minkowski space. If we take this hypersurface as the surface of a sphere whose radius tends to infinity we have that the integral has to be zero both for the spacial and the time infinite. I get the flux of $J^\mu$ being zero when integrated over the spacial part, and that makes the spacial part of the integral 0. What I don't get is how and why the integral is 0 at the time infinity?

I'm sorry if the question is not totally clear, that's the clearest version that is in my mind right now, I didn't completely grasp the problem, anyway any advice to improve it and any answer to my doubts are kindly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a total divergence inside the integral

Comment: @BobBee  What do you mean? Isn't it a 4-divergence?

Comment: You have a 4 divergence and another term, the current. dont you need the divergence only?

Comment: @BobBee I think you're right, I may have miscopied from my notes, cause the professor said we were gonna apply the Gauss theorem so I assume I made a mistake copying, I check right now.

Comment: @BobBee No, we have a total divergence at the beginning  $ \partial_\mu^{\,'}  D J^\mu$ but using the chain rule we obtain $(\partial_\mu^{\,'} D)J^\mu + D \, \partial_\mu^{\,'} J^\mu$ with the second term null for the continuity equation. So I guess we should have used the Gauss theorem in the first place, before using the chain, this just increases my confusion, why doing that first and then applying Gauss?

Comment: Maybe just a little care. First, your equation is right so far but only because there was an intermediate step, not the continuity equation. The derivative inside the integral is wrt to x, not x prime. Since j is not dependent on x you just do it on G and because x-x prime appears, it's the negative, as you have it. Next you do an integration by parts, and the continuity equation gives you zero for the integral part, and you have jG evaluated at infinity. If there are no charges at infinity you get 0

Comment: @BobBee Ok thanks a lot for your help now it is clearer and and I have way less confusion, what about the time infinity, why should it be 0 there?